# What to do to make a map in the iphone Application?

Tags: iphone

I am New phone Application Developer and i want to develop an Application which contains maps so will you please give me some information regarding how to load map in my application?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [MapKit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/). The specifics of this API are too expansive to discuss in this answer (and you didn't provide us with a description of what exactly you want to achieve), but look at the documentation for the [MKMapView class](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) and its [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html).

Also, there are some 80 questions on Stack Overflow [tagged "MapKit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapkit).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post about the [iPhone Map Kit](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/).

If you don't understand it you should first play around with the iPhone SDK / Objective-C and get more familiar with it.